# Django display list items based on URL

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to hide/show sections of my navigation depending on my active URL.

I have attempted to do this using the `re.match()` method, but jinja did not like this. This code is in an HTML include file for my side navigation and is as follows:

```
<ul>
{% if bool(re.match('^/url/path', request.get_full_path)) %}
    <li><a href='link1'>Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href='link1'>Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href='link1'>Link3</a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) and use it. Something like this maybe;

```
# nav_active.py
import re
from django.template import Library
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

register = Library()

@register.filter()
def nav_active(request_path, search_path):
    # WRITE YOUR LOGIC
    return search_path in request_path
```

Inside the template

```
{% load nav_active %}
{% if request_path|nav_active:"/search/path" %}
....
{% endif %}
```

---

Update as per your comment. From Django [docs code layout section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) for custom template tags and filters:

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the **init**.py file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

So create a folder at same level as your `view.py` and name it `templatetags`. (Don't forget to add `__init__.py` inside). At the same level of that `__init__.py` add your `nav_active.py` and it should be ready to use. Like this:

```
yourapp/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  views.py
  templatetags/
     __init__.py
     nav_active.py
```

Comment: I am new to django, so I'm not sure where to put the nav_active.py file. I placed it in the directory of an installed app that I have but i get the following error: 'nav_active' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_static admin_urls cache future i18n l10n log static staticfiles tz. Where should I put the nav_active.py file?

Comment: Updated with extra info, hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!! Yes, my jinja filter now works. Thank you so much.